# Show notification message on custom phtml file?

Tags: magento2, messages

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages2">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder2" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages2" as="messages2" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</block>
```

and in phtml file 
`<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('page.messages2') ?>`

How to show notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in template   `account/dashboard/info.phtml`

```
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('ajax.message.placeholder2') ?>
```

Using above code you are calling child block which name is **message2**

Comment: But I want to show  Ajax based notification.  $block->getChildHtml('messages2') this is showing on page refresh.

Comment: updated answer please check it

Comment: Thanks Prashant, I was able to do it. But my question was how does it work.? what should I return from controller and what should I do in jquery response function ? Plwase help

Comment: If it helps you please mark as excepted for further use. Please post new question with full detail and code it would better someone can help you and understand what you want

Comment: done. I have added 1 more question. Can you please help me in this http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/147779/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You have keep wrong name in childHtml function in phtml file,

**Container name is not support inside getChildHtml() function. so you have to keep below code in your template file and check.**

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer_account_dashboard_info') ?>
```

Clear cache.